# Given two graph points determine in what direction the second point is from the first

Tags: java, math, coordinates

Given two graph points determine in what direction (N, NE, NW, E, W, S, SE, SW) the second point is from the first and display. If points are the same display 'here'.

I could calculate the angle between two points but still couldn't figure out a way to calculate direction of other point with respect the first point.

For Example, below are the coordinates of two points

```
int x1 = 1;
int x2 = 2;
int y1 = 3;
int y2 = 4;

Math.toDegrees( (Math.atan2(y_diff, x_diff))+360 ) % 360
```

Comment: It is to determine that point 1 is in which direction (N, NE, NW, E, W, S, SE, SW) to other point

Comment: You're overthinking this. You don't need angles. Just figure out whether the x-coordinate of the second point is less than that of the first, and if so it's to the west. So on and so forth. (Assuming north is in the +y direction and east is in the +x direction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following approach.

Create an empty string and first compare your `y` coordinates (because the two-letter direction always starts with 'N' or 'S'). Add 'N' or 'S' only if `y` coordinates are not equal (because if they equal, the direction is either 'E', 'W' or 'here'). Then do the same with `x` coordinates. If they are not equal, 'E' or 'W' will be added to the string.

I used JavaScript here to demonstrate how it works. This code can be easily rewritten in Java.

```js
const direction = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
    let d = "";
    d += y1 < y2 ? "N" : y1 > y2 ? "S" : "";
    d += x1 < x2 ? "E" : x1 > x2 ? "W" : "";
    return d === "" ? "here" : d;
};

console.log(direction(1, 2, 3, 4)); //NE
console.log(direction(4, 2, 5, 1)); //SE
console.log(direction(0, 0, 0, 1)); //N
console.log(direction(3, 2, 1, 1)); //SW
console.log(direction(0, 1, 2, 1)); //E
console.log(direction(0, 0, 0, 0)); //here
```

Comment: @Prasoon I was glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the direction by comparing your x, y coordinates,
For an example your input is,

```
int x1  = 1;
int x2  = 2;
int y1  = 3;
int y2  = 4;
```

Then calculate the following,

x2 - x1 (equals 1)

y2 - y1 (equals 1)

That means point 1 is located to the left of point 2 and point 1 is located below point 2

Which means it is pointing between North and East. After calculating the angle you can determine exact direction.